# Why are the images in this PDF file corrupt in some viewers?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

We are using [PDFsharp](http://pdfsharp.net/) to gather sets of images from a folder and put them into PDF files, one image per page. For this certain set of images, the resulting PDF document appears corrupted when opening in certain viewers... [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6k72.jpg) is broken, [Adobe Reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd8kz.jpg) is broken, [Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Nw9.jpg) gives up entirely, but [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jb5R.jpg) actually renders it correctly.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public static List<string> ImageExtensions()
{
    return new List<string>() { ".tif", ".tiff", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif" };
}

public void Convert()
{
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

    foreach(string fPath in FilePaths)
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(fPath);
        if (ImageExtensions().Contains(ext))
            AddImageToPDF(fPath, ref doc);
    }
    try
    {
        doc.Save(OutputFilePath);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    doc.Close();
    doc.Dispose();            
}

private void AddImageToPDF(string imagePath, ref PdfDocument doc)
{
    Image MyImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
    AddImageToPDF(MyImage, ref doc);
}

private void AddImageToPDF(Image image, ref PdfDocument doc)
{
    try
    {
        int numPages = doc.Pages.Count;
        using (Image MyImage = image)
        {
            for (int _pageIndex = 0; _pageIndex < MyImage.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page); _pageIndex++)
            {
                MyImage.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, _pageIndex);

                XImage img = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(MyImage);
                img.Interpolate = true;

                var page = new PdfPage() { Orientation = img.PixelWidth > img.PixelHeight ? PageOrientation.Landscape : PageOrientation.Portrait };
                doc.Pages.Add(page);

                using (var xg = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[_pageIndex + numPages]))
                {
                    xg.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[File set A](https://ufile.io/r4r2g3c1) (broken in most viewers). [File set B](https://ufile.io/cswv1ctv) (working in all viewers). Both sets are JPEGs that were converted from PNGs using the exact same mechanism (Irfanview).

Why do all of the viewers except Firefox render A incorrectly, and what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I would split the string at points `yourString.split('.')` and select the last element of the splitted array: `splittedString[splittedString.length - 1]`

Comment: I currently cannot inspect your files but usually you can count on Adobe Reader rendering valid files correctly (it also renders many invalid files *somehow* making live hard for other implementers of the pdf standard but it usually does not fail to render valid files correctly). Thus, most likely those files in question indeed are broken.

Comment: Firefox renders correctly because it ignores flags specified in the PDF file. PDFsharp sets those flags based on information returned by the Windows framework. Also see my answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am an idiot... updating to the latest version of PDFSharp fixed the issue. I had assumed we were already using the latest. >=/

Answer (score 0):

For images with just a single frame you should use `XImage.FromFile` instead of `XImage.FromGdiPlusImage` to work around a bug somewhere in recent versions of the Windows framework.

XImage.FromFile allows PDFsharp to access the original file while XImage.FromGdiPlusImage must rely on the information provided by the framework - and for certain JPEG images this information is not correct.

Make sure you are using the latest version of PDFsharp. Good questions indicate which version they refer to.

You should get correct PDF files if you run your code under Windows XP (but that ain't an option for production use, of course).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but XImage.FromFile produces the same results.

Comment: It seems you are currently using the GDI build of PDFsharp. You can give the WPF build a try. You can also try a different image converter (MS Paint can be used to convert single images manually). I don't have time to debug this issue at the moment.